# JMETER: Getting timestamp error in log file when giving CSV filename in Summary Report

Tags: jmeter, performance, csv-file

When I am giving a CSV filename path in Summary Report, I get an error to see log file. I see log file and it shows:

```
2019-01-30 14:23:38,146 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Unknown column name 
2019-01-30 14:23:38,146 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: C:\Users\abdullah.bin\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.0\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\CSV\Results.csv does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration.
2019-01-30 14:23:38,147 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Cannot parse timestamp: '', will try following formats [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss]
2019-01-30 14:23:38,147 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, trying next date format
2019-01-30 14:23:38,148 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2019-01-30 14:23:38,148 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, trying next date format
2019-01-30 14:23:38,149 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2019-01-30 14:23:38,149 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2019-01-30 14:23:38,149 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1. java.text.ParseException: No date-time format found matching 
2019-01-30 14:23:38,149 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: C:\Users\abdullah.bin\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.0\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\CSV\Results.csv
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.text.ParseException: No date-time format found matching
```

I can see it is a timestamp error but I am clueless where do I need to change? When JMeter exports CSV it does work but when I create and save CSV to export to it shows this error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am facing the same issue
csv looks like this: ```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1674615764946,5632,reset,200,OK,REST Thread Group 1-9,text,true,"No Nodes Matched for //resultCode[text()=""0""]",1002,1038,10,10,http://10.3.0.22:8080/axis/services/DeviceController,5630,0,1697
1674615764975,6547,reset,200,OK,REST Thread Group 1-10,text,true,"No Nodes Matched for //resultCode[text()=""0""]",1002,1038,10,10,http://10.3.0.22:8080/axis/servi

Answer (score 2):

Normally .jtl results file should look like:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1548814963190,68,Some Sampler,200,OK,127.0.0.1-Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,114,0,2,2,null,21,0,3
1548814963100,236,Some Other Sampler,200,OK,127.0.0.1-Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,114,0,3,3,null,32,0,5
etc.
```

If your CSV file differs from above - probably something is wrong with it or with JMeter [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Try [re-running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t your_test.jmx -l result.csv
```

And JMeter should produce the CSV file similar to what I provided above suitable for opening with [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) or generating the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I tried running in Non-GUI mode just like you said and this is the output I got:
`timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect`

`1548846677886,2379,HTTP Request,200,,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,48498,148,3,3,://yes.xyz.com/login.html,2140,0,1617`

So it seems I got the right format. Seems some issue with my Excel maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the timestamp format in the CSV file. It seems like the default timestamp format is not matching with the timestamp format in the CSV file.

To resolve the issue, you can update the CSV file and make sure it has the correct timestamp format. JMeter supports multiple timestamp formats, you can see the list of supported formats in the log message:

*"Cannot parse timestamp: '', will try following formats [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss]"*

Update the timestamp in the CSV file to match one of the above formats and try again.